# ListView not scrolling when add items at runtime. LinearLayout inside ScrollView neither does it work

Tags: android, runtime, scrollview, items

I have one listview inside constraintLayout. I add items at runtime in listView. When items exceed the visible part of listView, it does not move up or down to show hidden items.
I have tried changing listView by linearLayout inside scrollView but the same thing happens.
I've done enough tests and I think the problem is on xml layout file.
Is a fragment over other fragment (I had to set clickable property to true on constraintlayout parent).
[image: this is how my problem looks]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".CrearTurno">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_tv_comentario"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/crear_turno_tv_comentario"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_horacomienzo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_bt_colorfondo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/crear_turno_tv_colorfondo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_bt_colortexto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_etx_comentario" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_etx_horasturno"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_horasturno"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_etx_abreviatura" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_tv_horasturno"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/crear_turno_tv_horasturno"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_abreviatura"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_abreviatura" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_tv_abreviatura"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/crear_turno_tv_abreviatura"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_itemturno" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_etx_abreviatura"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_abreviatura"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_itemturno" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_etx_comentario"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
        android:lines="4"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_comentario" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_etx_horacomienzo2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="08:00"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_horacomienzo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_etx_horasturno" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_tv_horacomienzo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/crear_turno_tv_horacomienzo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_tv_horasturno" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_itemturno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_bti_agregarturno"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_turno_tv_letraturno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:paddingLeft="12sp"
            android:paddingTop="6sp"
            android:paddingRight="12sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6sp"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_bt_colortexto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/crear_turno_tv_colortexto"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crear_turno_bt_colorfondo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crear_turno_etx_comentario" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/crear_turno_bti_agregarturno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crear_turno_linearvisorparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Class that make the work:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;



import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.azeesoft.lib.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog;
import com.tron.miturno.utilidades.myTools;
import com.tron.miturno.vistas_personalizadas.vistaTurno;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CrearTurno extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    /**
     * Una forma de pasar valores a un fragment antes de que se inicialice
     * En este caso no paso nada.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static CrearTurno NewInstance() {
        CrearTurno edf = new CrearTurno();
        // edf.setLstDiasDelMes(listaDias);
        return edf;
    }

    public CrearTurno() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static int ColorFondoSeleccionado, ColorTextoSeleccionado;
    private AppCompatTextView tvMuestraAbreviatura;
    private LinearLayout linearMuestraFondo;
    private Button btColorTexto, btColorFondo;
    private ImageButton btiAgregaTurno;
    private EditText etxEditAbreviatura, etxEditHoras, etxEditHoraComienzo, etxEditNotas;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private listaTurnosAdapter listaTurnosAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Turno> listaTurnos = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crear_turno, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_recyclerturnos);

        tvMuestraAbreviatura = view.findViewById(R.id.item_turno_tv_letraturno);
        tvMuestraAbreviatura.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
        linearMuestraFondo = view.findViewById(R.id.item_turno_linearfondo);
        linearMuestraFondo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.marron));

        ColorFondoSeleccionado = getResources().getColor(R.color.marron);
        ColorTextoSeleccionado = getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco);

        btColorTexto = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_bt_colortexto);
        btColorFondo = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_bt_colorfondo);
        btiAgregaTurno = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_bti_agregarturno);
        etxEditAbreviatura = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_etx_abreviatura);
        etxEditAbreviatura.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (count < 1) return;
                tvMuestraAbreviatura.setText(s.toString().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
                etxEditAbreviatura.setText("");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        etxEditHoras = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_etx_horasturno);
        etxEditHoraComienzo = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_etx_horacomienzo2);
        etxEditNotas = view.findViewById(R.id.crear_turno_etx_comentario);

        linearMuestraFondo.setOnClickListener(this);
        btiAgregaTurno.setOnClickListener(this);
        btColorTexto.setOnClickListener(this);
        btColorFondo.setOnClickListener(this);

        listaTurnosAdapter = new listaTurnosAdapter(getActivity(), listaTurnos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listaTurnosAdapter);


        return view;
    }

    private void mostrarColorPicked(final boolean colorLetra) {
        /*****************************************************************************************
         * https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3143   Para ver detalles del colorpicker
         ****************************************************************************************/

        ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog =
                ColorPickerDialog.createColorPickerDialog(getActivity(), ColorPickerDialog.DARK_THEME);
        colorPickerDialog.setInitialColor(R.color.blanco);
        colorPickerDialog.hideOpacityBar();
        colorPickerDialog.hideHexaDecimalValue();
        colorPickerDialog.setOnColorPickedListener(new ColorPickerDialog.OnColorPickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onColorPicked(int color, String hexVal) {
                if (colorLetra) {
                    ColorTextoSeleccionado = color;
                    tvMuestraAbreviatura.setTextColor(color);
                } else {
                    ColorFondoSeleccionado = color;
                    linearMuestraFondo.setBackgroundColor(color);
                }
            }
        });
        colorPickerDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.crear_turno_bt_colortexto:
                mostrarColorPicked(true);
                break;
            case R.id.crear_turno_bt_colorfondo:
                mostrarColorPicked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.crear_turno_bti_agregarturno:
                agregarTurnoAlVisor();
                break;
            case R.id.item_turno_linearfondo:
                // Si presiono sobre el turno de muestra, se añade al visor de turnos
                agregarTurnoAlVisor();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void agregarTurnoAlVisor() {
        //////  HSCE FALTA CHEQUEAR LOS EDITTEXT Y DEMAS CAMPOS PARA QUE TENGAN VALORES OK
        /***** TEST ONLY ******/
        etxEditHoras.setText("6");
        etxEditHoraComienzo.setText(myTools.convertDateToTimeString(new Date()));
        /**** TEST ONLY ******/
        Turno turno = new Turno();
        turno.setColorFondo(ColorFondoSeleccionado);
        turno.setColorTexto(ColorTextoSeleccionado);
        turno.setAbreviatura(tvMuestraAbreviatura.getText().toString());

        int nh = Integer.parseInt(etxEditHoras.getText().toString());
        turno.setNumHoras(nh);
        Date horaCom = myTools.convertStringTimeToDate(etxEditHoraComienzo.getText().toString());
        turno.setHoraComienzo(horaCom);
        turno.setNotaTurno(etxEditNotas.getText().toString() + "");

        listaTurnos.add(turno);
        listaTurnosAdapter.notifyData(listaTurnos);

    }

    private class adapterRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterRecycler.vistaTurnoHolder>{

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public adapterRecycler.vistaTurnoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull vistaTurnoHolder holder, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        class vistaTurnoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public AppCompatTextView txvLetra;
             adapterRecycler mAdapter;

            public vistaTurnoHolder(@NonNull View itemView, AppCompatTextView txvLetra, adapterRecycler mAdapter) {
                super(itemView);
                this.txvLetra = txvLetra;
                this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
            }

            public vistaTurnoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
            }
        }
    }

    /******************************************************************************************
     ******************************************************************************************
     ***
     ***                      CLASE DEL ADAPTADOR PARA EL LIST VIEW
     ***
     ******************************************************************************************
     ******************************************************************************************/
    private class adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<vistaTurno> listaVistaTurnos=new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Turno> listaTurnos;
        private CrearTurno listener;

        /**
         * Adaptador para mostrar en el ListView los items añadidos
         * listenerForOnClickItem es la propia clase que crea el adaptador, que debe implementar
         * View.OnCLickListener
         *
         * @param context
         * @param lista
         * @param listenerForOnClickItem
         */
        public adaptador(Context context, ArrayList<Turno> lista, CrearTurno listenerForOnClickItem) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listaTurnos = lista;
            this.listener = listenerForOnClickItem;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            Turno turno = listaTurnos.get(i);
            if (turno != null)
                listaVistaTurnos.remove(turno);

            vistaTurno vTurno = new vistaTurno(turno, context);
            //Consigo que al pulsarsobre un vista se active onclick en la clase
            vTurno.setOnClickListener(this.listener);
            listaVistaTurnos.add(vTurno);

            return vTurno;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int n = listaTurnos.size();
            return n;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return listaTurnos.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }


        public vistaTurno getTurno(int i) {
            return listaVistaTurnos.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **RecyclerView** for your list. It's more optimized for storing lists. Check this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-create-recycler-view/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0) for the detailed instructions on how to implement and use it.

Comment: I started using linearLayout vertical because de list is very simple, max 15-20 items. I was adding items dynamically to linearlayout (inside scrollview) but the same issue. Later I tryed a ListView, but same happend. When add items the scrollbars not appear, if I try to move items in up or down direction touching over it, nothing happend. I have tryed the same listview in clear xml file and it's run perfectly, but in my xml layout file not working. Thanks.

Comment: Can u share the class which populates listView on github?

Comment: Hi! I just add de class that make de work. It's possible that problem are in how I'm working with these Fragments??